# Swift 3/4 How to animate contentMode of UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

My goal is when I click on button to toggle contentMode: scaleAspectFit & scaleAspectFill with animation.

```
    @IBAction func toggleContentModeAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    if sender.isSelected {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.popImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.popImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

but no effective to my goal. Please fix for me, thanks from Cambodia.

Comment: Wow, however it's not fit to my goal, but it can use perfectly. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `contentMode`, itself, is not an animatable property. But you can animated between two different renditions of a view with [`transition(with:duration:options:animations:completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622574-transition), e.g.

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let contentMode: UIViewContentMode = imageView.contentMode == .scaleAspectFill ? .scaleAspectFit : .scaleAspectFill

    UIView.transition(with: imageView, duration: 1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        self.imageView.contentMode = contentMode
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

That yields:

[image]